# Retrieving password from Polkadot js extention

Tags: google-chrome-extension, cryptojs, polkadot, polkadot-js

hey as the title hints to, yes i have managed to loose the mnemonic phrase for my polkadot js wallet in the event of staking and creating the account. In addition i have forgot the password to the wallet itself. Now my question is if it is possible in some miraculous way to retrieve the password (cryptical key) out of my Chrome extension folder on my macbook pro as I at least am logged into the account?

[image]

Comment: You can write a personal email to the extension's author.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. Your password is what's used to encrypt the wallet keys stored in the extension. Storing the password in the extension itself would be quite pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Chrome settings where Passwords are stored. There i retrieved mine!

Enjoy

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).